The double left continuous inverse is equal to the left continuous version of the function
I have some non-decreasing function $f$, and I will denote the left continuous inverse of $f$ as $f^{\leftarrow}(y)=inf\{x:f(x)\geq y\}$. Now I want to prove:
$$(f^{\leftarrow})^{\leftarrow}(x)=f^{-}(x),$$
where $f^{-}$ denotes the "left-continuous version" of $f$. I am thinking, that it is sufficient to prove, that they have the same points of continuity, but I have trouble proving it

At first we note that $f^{\leftarrow}(f(y))\leq y$ for all $y$, since of course $f(y)\geq f(y)$.
We have to prove that $\inf\{y: f^{\leftarrow}(y)\geq x\}=\sup_{y<x}f(y)$, but for $y<x$ we have $f^{\leftarrow}(f(y))\leq y<x$, so $\inf\{y: f^{\leftarrow}(y)\geq x\}\geq f(y)$ and in particular $\inf\{y: f^{\leftarrow}(y)\geq x\}\geq\sup_{y<x}f(y)$.
Moreover if we take a $z> \sup_{y<x}f(y)$, we note that $f^{\leftarrow}(z)\geq x$ since $f(y)<z$ for all $y<x$, so $z\geq \inf\{y: f^{\leftarrow}(y)\geq x\}$ and in particular $\inf\{y: f^{\leftarrow}(y)\geq x\}\leq\sup_{y<x}f(y)$.
All these steps required a good dose of attention, and all the choices about strong or weak inequalities ($<$ or $\leq$) have a good reason to be like that.
